# Cannot include unistd.h in Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, include

I need to traverse all current processes with DFS(Depth First Search) in linux with C. I need to get parent process name and parent process id of the process named gedit. I'm trying to use getppid function. Here is the code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

// Not sure of these two include statements:
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* performs a depth-first traversal of the list of tasks in the system. */
void traverse(struct task_struct *ptr) {
    struct list_head *list;
    struct task_struct *next_task;
    pid_t ppid;

    if ((thread_group_leader(ptr)) && (strcmp(ptr->comm,"gedit")==0)) {
              ppid = getppid();
              printk(KERN_INFO "PID:%d\n",ppid); }

    list_for_each(list, &ptr->children) {
        next_task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
        traverse(next_task);
    }
}

int simple_init(void)
{
     printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");
     printk(KERN_INFO "Gedit's parent process:\n");
     traverse(&init_task);
     return 0;
}

void simple_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
}

module_init( simple_init );
module_exit( simple_exit );
```

I get this error: unistd.h no such file or directory
If I try to include linux/unistd.h, I get implicit decleration of getppid function error.

Traversal works, the only problem is libraries and getppid function. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There's an alternative option called [for_each_process()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L565) which gets all the task_structs present in the system.I'm not a kernel developer , but I think you can use it instead.By getting the task_structs , you can get their PIDs via tsk->real_parent->pid.

Comment: Yes, I can reach the parent with for_each_process(), thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with kernel code. There's no C standard library in the kernel! You cannot include standard headers like `unistd.h` or use most C standard library functions like `getppid()`.

If you want to get the PID of the current parent process from a kernel module you can get it from `current->real_parent`.

```
rcu_read_lock();
ppid = rcu_dereference(current->real_parent)->pid;
rcu_read_unlock();
```